# How does WordPress tell which post is from which site in a multisite setup?

Tags: multisite

I'm aware that WordPress stores all the post content of a multisite in the same database table and I was just wondering how it internally differentiates post content from one blog to the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posts from one site are not stored in the same table as posts from another site.

Each blog on a multi site gets an ID and that ID is used to generate a separate set of tables for each site in a multisite installation.

So for example site 1 gets:

```
wp_posts
```

where as site 2 gets:

```
wp_1_posts
```

and so on:

```
wp_2_posts
```